# List of language-related Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, faq

This is a list of language-related Stack Exchange sites. If your target language is not listed here, please consider creating a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

See also:

- [Language learning website outside Stack exchange](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/language-learning-website-outside-stack-exchange)

Comment: There is a [similar list](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/217/11052) on French Language Stack Exchange (though the updates are less frequent).

Comment: Where do I ask a question about the difference between 2 Arabic letters when no Arabic SE exists & how exactly is that not relevant to language learning? My understanding has always been that learning a language's alphabet was a key part of learning the language, but maybe I'm wrong. Here's the question if you want it. https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4969/7857

Comment: @jastako: This site is for asking about learning and teaching _techniques_. Your question falls under the first example of [off-topic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions: "Questions about grammar, spelling, phonetics, or other aspects of a specific language." As for where you can ask such a question: I'm afraid I don't know. There's obviously not a stack exchange site for every possible question.

Answer (score 18):

For a list of other language-learning resources not hosted by StackExchange, see [this post](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/13).

Sites about languages in general, but not about a specific language:

- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) (this site)
- [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/) (mostly about *how* to create new languages; not about learning them)

Language-specific sites, in alphabetical order by language:

- [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)
- English:

  - [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
  - [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)
- [Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/)
- [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/)
- [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/)
- [Italian](https://italian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- [Korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/)
- [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/)
- [Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)
- Russian:

  - in [English](https://russian.stackexchange.com/): Russian Language Stack Exchange
  - in [Russian](https://rus.stackexchange.com/): Русский язык.
- [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ukrainian](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/)

On Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange, some [questions tagged `language-processing`](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-processing) may be relevant to language learning.

Answer (score 17):

### Proposed Language Sites (Area 51)

The sites are listed in alphabetical order. As long as a proposed site is in the definition stage, questions can be submitted and upvoted but not be answered.

- <s>[Arabic Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language): proposed 8 February 2020</s>; closed on 10 February 2020.
- <s>[Danish Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123629/danish-language): proposed on 1 January 2020</s>; closed on 16 February 2020.
- <s>[Swahili Language & Usage](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122852/swahili-language-usage): proposed on 05 August 2019</s>; closed due to inactivity.
- <s>[Greek Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123680/greek-language): proposed on 8 January 2020</s>; closed due to inactivity.
- <s>[Dutch Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122507/dutch-language): proposed on 16 June 2019</s>; closed on 17 October 2019.
- <s>[Samoan Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123636/samoan-language): proposed on 2 January 2020</s>; closed on 12 February 2020.
- <s>[Sanskrit Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language): proposed on 17 October 2019</s>; closed on 18 February 2020.
- <s>[Hindi Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67907/hindi-language): proposed on (?)</s>; closed on (?).
- <s>[Tamil Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123232/tamil-language): proposed on 9 October 2019</s>; closed on 10 February 2020.
- <s>[Crimean Tatar Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125418/crimean-tatar-language), proposed around 9 March 2021;</s> closed as "not viable" on 5 May 2021.

All such proposals are currently closed.