# Resources for Researching Language Learning Questions

Tags: discussion, faq, community-wiki, unanswered-questions

At the time of writing, 49 out of our 315 questions are [tagged with `reference-request`](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), and at least 10 of these are still unanswered. (We have 20 unanswered questions in total.) In addition, I think that the number of questions tagged [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) will probably increase. For this reason, I think it's a good idea to create a **community wiki that lists resources for answering questions that ask for scientific evidence**.

When someone answers a question without citing references, we can refer them to this community wiki.

**Update 07.09.2017**: 14 out of [40 unanswered questions](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) are tagged with [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

**Update 24.10.2021**: We currently have [30 unanswered questions tagged `reference-request`](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+answers%3A0) out of a total of [182 questions without an answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 4):

Using search engines more effectively:

- [Power Searching with Google](http://www.powersearchingwithgoogle.com/).

Specialised search engines and catalogues:

- [Bielefeld Academic Search Engine / BASE](https://www.base-search.net/?l=en): a search engine specifically [for academic web resources](https://www.base-search.net/about/en/).
- [Paperity](http://paperity.org/): an aggregator of [Open Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access) journals and papers.
- [CORE](https://core.ac.uk/search/): another aggregator of open access research outputs.
- [Zetoc](http://zetoc.mimas.ac.uk/): search engine that indexes over 30,000 journals.
- [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/) is "the world's largest library catalog". WorldCat helps you locate books in a large number of libraries, so you can find out whether a specific book is available in a (university) library near you.
- [COPAC](http://copac.jisc.ac.uk/): online catalogue for specialised libraries in the UK and Ireland.
- [Europeana](http://www.europeana.eu/portal/en): meta-catalogue of cultural heritage collections in Europe.

Sites with public access:

- [ERIC](http://eric.ed.gov/) indexes research papers related to education, including research on second language acquisition. ERIC always provides an abstract but does not always store the paper itself.
- [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/): search engine that indexes academic literature.

Sites with both free and paid resources:

- [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/): archive of academic publications. There is a free registration option that allows you to read up to 3 articles every 2 weeks.
- [Springer Link](http://link.springer.com/): Springer is an academic publisher; some of the papers on its website are available as Open Access documents.
- [Elsevier's SciencDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/): Elsevier is another big academic publisher. Some of the papers available on SciencDirect are available as Open Access publications.