# Language learning or teaching websites outside Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

What other websites exist where one can ask questions about learning or teaching languages?

See also:

- [Resources for Researching Language Learning Questions](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/resources-for-researching-language-learning-questions)
- [List of language-related Stack Exchange sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/438/list-of-language-related-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 2):

- [Languages and linguistics Codidact](https://languages.codidact.com/) is a question and answer site, whose title explains the scope.
- [Duolingo forums](https://forum.duolingo.com/) are a feature of the commercial Duolingo language learning website.

Answer (score 0):

### Arabic

- [Rocket Languages Arabic Forum](https://www.rocketlanguages.com/forum/arabic)
- [Learn Arabic and Other Languages - Ummah.com](https://www.ummah.com/forum/forum/library/learn-arabic-and-other-languages)
- [How to learn Arabic](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Saudi-Arabia/Forums/Language/How-to-learn-Arabic)