# How is asking a question about the difference between 2 letters not relevant to language learning?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question about the difference between ی and ي with the tag #arabic because I checked Area51 & an Arabic SE does not exist, & was told it was off-topic which is absurd. I would post the link but I'm sure you can't see it because like I said it was marked as off-topic & closed.[Here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4969/7857)'s the link anyway. If there's any moderators here feel free to provide me an explanation before marking this as off-topic too.

Comment: BTW I checked Area51 The suggestion for an Arabic language SE was closed, therefore there is no other relevant place to ask the link question. Not on SE anyway..As I said marking a question that IS a part of learning a language as off-topic makes no sense.

Comment: SE does not have an obligation to present a website for every question. For this particular one you could try Codidact: https://languages.codidact.com/

Comment: The difficulty is primarily that, as you have suggested, arabic.stackexchange.com *would* be the place to post your question if only it existed. ... and it doesn't, so there ain't no place to put it on stackexchange. Fortunately, other sites exist.

Answer (score 3):

Language Learning Stack Exchange is a site for questions about how to learn or teach specific languages and specific language skills, and about finding resources for languages for which few resources exist.

Languages present many difficulties to language learners. How to overcome these difficulties is within the scope of this site. Explaining the differences between certain words, characters, spellings, grammar usages, however, is outside the scope of this site, even though these difficulties present barriers to learners.

Comment: I'm really surprised that is considered outside of the scope, but where is a good place to ask that question? There isn't an Arabic SE as stated in the question. I don't have any interest in creating a new account. I asked the question because I'm adapting Arabic to English based on a wordpress adaptation, rather than trying to learn Arabic, so I only ask a question now & then. Would conlang SE be appropriate?

Comment: Conlang SE is specifically for constructed languages (e.g. Esperanto, Klingon, Dothraki, etc.) not for natural languages. For now, I have listed a few forums outside Stack Exchange in the post [Language learning or teaching websites outside Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/691/800).