# Please consider following the Sanskrit proposal

Tags: discussion

I believe many users of this community would be interested in Sanskrit site proposal and there is a Sanskrit language proposal on Area51 live! Do please consider following it.

Here is the link:

[image]

We also need hands to define the scope and adding more questions and/or other contributions.

Thanks.

> **Note1**: I tried reaching [this community members](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52314177#52314177) on the main chatroom before directly posting here but after getting no response from any users for a long time, I decided to post here. Please feel free to close if this is against the CoC of this community.
>
> **Note2**: Asked a [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335906/196352) before promoting here. I didn't get thoughts to make it a discussion one.

Comment: I hope we will get more supports for this for qualifying definition phase.

Comment: I have added it to the [list of proposed sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/442/800).

Comment: To my knowledge, this is the third Sanskrit language proposal since 2016. If you want this one to succeed, please promote it also outside Stack Exchange, e.g. on Reddit and Twitter.

Comment: Sure @AModHasNoName. Thanks for the support here!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I am posting some information regarding new site proposals and the future of Area51:

- Community building for a new site should start before a new site is proposed, not after it; see [Where should I start building the community for a new Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309634/340816) on Meta SE and [New site: Community requirement](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31204/160337).
- [The future of Area 51 is still uncertain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344244/340816) by JNat in February 2020 on Meta SE.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a proposal for a [Tamil language site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123232/tamil-language). Even though I am not currently learning any Indo-Iranian or Dravidian language (rather, I am currently concentrating in the Romance and Semitic groups), I managed to learn a few things by just reading through the proposals and trying to come up with one or two questions. Keep it up!

I have also added the Tamil proposal to the [linked CW](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/442/2167).