# Please don't migrate proofreading questions to English Language Learners

Tags: discussion, migration

Please don't migrate questions like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294430/could-you-help-correct-this-paragraph):

> **Could you help correct this paragraph** [closed]
>
> I had started working a full-time job since I wasn't graduated. After
> almost 2 years of working, I find myself exhausted and lost. I decided
> to take a gap year in 2022 to resort everything and gain my skills.
> I'm so excited about next year, I earned enough money and now I can
> live with my family, doing things I love and hopefully come out to be
> a better version of myself.

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is clear that asking the community to check text for errors is off-topic. At a minimum, the author should identify what part of the text they're having trouble with. This post on EL&U's meta explains a bit more why these sorts of migrations are a problem for ELL: [Please don't migrate obviously off-topic questions to ELL - it just makes things harder on the author](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11075/80039)

Migrating a question is not migrating a user. If you think ELL would be helpful to someone even though their question isn't on-topic, by all means suggest they check us out. Please don't make it harder for them by migrating an off-topic question that can't be salvaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this issue. From my side, I'll take a close look at ELL's "on-topic" page in future.

Some time ago, I also asked (on this Meta), [whether we need a custom close reason for migrations to ELL](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/800). So far, this question has remained in limbo due to low participation on meta. A custom close reason may be able to reflect ELL's scope better than the current generic close reasons, but perhaps the custom close reason would be undesirable from the point of view of ELL mods. Should this turn out to be the case, we can put that question to rest.

Comment: Thanks. Migration is super confusing the way it’s implemented. I found this post on Meta helpful in understanding it when I had just started out as a mod: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/273494